# Porting Xamarin Forms Android version to Blackberry 10

Tags: c#, blackberry, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have Xamarin Forms PCL project and I am trying to port Android version to Balckberry. I use Blackberry APK Packager, Blackberry Signer and Blackberry Deploy. I was successful to deploy my Android version to Blackberry 10.2.1, 10.3 and 10.3.1 and launch it. My application works good on BB, but whenever I call async/await method it fails.
Do you know how the .NET asynchronous methods are translated to Java? Or give me any idea, how can I fix this problem? 
I am not able to determine the exception, because I don't have debugger.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? Also, can you post a stack trace and some code? I'm thinking of doing the same thing and I'd like to see how this was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

IL code is not translated into Java. It is executed by Mono Runtime that runs aside with Dalvik (or ART).

Without stacktrace it is hard to determine real issue. 
From my experience, file IO fails on BB quite often. Try disabling all file IO to check tihs assumption, or even better get you debugger working and provide us with stacktrace